# ReplaySubject is not being called again in Angular 4

Tags: angular, observable, subject

I have a service with the following code:

```
private broadcast = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
public search(searchTerm: any, entity: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(service.searchUrl(searchTerm, entity))
    .map((res: Response) => {
        if(res){
            this.broadcast.next(res.json().results);
        }
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);  
}
```

From my app component, I'm calling this

```
ngOnInit() {
this.getAlbums('latest');  }

public getAlbums(searchTerm: string): any {
    this.searchService.search(searchTerm, 'album').subscribe(res => 
    this.defaultAlbums = res);  
}
```

This works fine in the first run.

When I go to a different page and come back to the home page where the list should be visible, it doesn't call the `search` function to retrieve the data

Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: is it caling `getAlbums` method

Comment: Yes, it's calling

Comment: if it's calling `getAlbums` method then it should invoke the `search` method.\

Comment: That's what my argument as well. But there's no service calls happening here when the `getAlbums` function called again

Comment: put a debugge and check where the code breaks

Comment: Looks like some cache issue, added the debugger and it works fine. Then removed it and no problem now. Thanks @SachilaRanawaka